# Applescript : open function Working on 10.9 not in 10.8

Tags: macos, cocoa, osx-mountain-lion, osx-mavericks

**Description :**

Currently i have c programming package which invokes an applescript by passing an argument.

From the applescript, i am trying to invoke my cocoa application by passing arguments to my application

Below is the applescript

**Case 1:**

```
on run argv
    do shell script ("open -n /Applications/File-Uploader.app/ --args " & "'" & item 1 of argv & "' ")
end run
```

If i run my c program package it will pass one argument to applescript, it works fine in  OSX 10.9.
but in 10.8 or lower, even the application(File-Uploader.app) not getting called from the above applescript.

I had checked whether there is any exception while passing argument from c programming package to apple script(By using 
the below applescript).

**Case 2 :**

```
on run argv --argv: list of strings like unix arguments passed
    set arg1 to item 1 of argv
    tell application "Finder" to display dialog ("Argument 1: " & arg1 as string)
end run
```

But it displayed the argument that passed from c programming package.

Can anyone advice on how to achieve the expected result on Case 1 in OSX 10.8 and lower versions ?

Is any build setting needs to be change in xcode on Archive the app to execute the apple script  ?

Is there any users permission to run the apple script on OSX 10.8 and lower versions ?

Comment: what is the `deployment target` setting for your app in XCode?

Comment: Currently in OSX 10.8 but i changed deployment target and base SDK to 10.7 and checked. But i can't achieve the expected result on Case 1 in OSX 10.8 and lower versions.

Comment: I have problem in do shell script only. tell application finder function works fine for me. but i can't able to send arugument to my application in tell application function.